# JQuery fadeTo() Function with scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrolltop, fadeto

I try to use fadeTo() in a scrollTop() function. First, I try it with fadeIn and fadeOut, that works perfect. But I want to keep the true height of the image. I changed the opacity in my css to 0 and want to show the image, when the scrollposition is between 30 and 200.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30 && $(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
                $("#amy").fadeTo("slow", 1);
            } else {
                $("#amy").fadeTo("slow", 0);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
#amy {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    max-width: 155px;

    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -khtml-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The if is working with fadeIn $ fadeOut, but not with fadeTo. Dont know why? Is fadeTo not supported with scrollTop?

Comment: Jquery "fadeto()" is used to adjust the opacity of the matched elements And in your example you set opacity 1 to 0. As i know the opacity 0 is hide element and opacity 1 is visible the selected element. If you only want to show and hide the div than why not use direct jquery "show()" or "hide()"?

Comment: fadeTo() use opacity and keep the original high of the element. When I use hide(), my container furls cause "display: none" delete the placeholder for the element.

Comment: I made the image with the boostrap 3.0.1 framework responsive and when I wrap the image in a div with fixed width and height, my responsive design is no responsive design anymore. Thats a second reason why I wont use hide(), cause it would work only with a wrapper div in my case.

Comment: Try to set "visibility" of element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `fadeTo` isn't working, but you can try `animate()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30 && $(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
            $("#amy").animate({opacity: 1}, "slow");
            return;
        } 
        $("#amy").animate({opacity: 0}, "slow");

    });
</script>
```

Also, make sure there is no other CSS on the element.  Like `visibility: hidden;` or anything like that.

Comment: added the css. When I made it simple without the pixelboundry it works.  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) is working finde, fadeTo 1 opacity. But when I use between >30 and <200, the opacity 0 is not set.

Comment: Then it's probably something to do with the conditional statement and nothing to do with the css at all.

Comment: I works only, when I use my mouse wheel, when I change the position of the scrollbar manually it wont work. Thats crazy...

Comment: That is pretty odd.  I'm just throw out ideas now, but maybe try "body" or "html" instead of document and see if that helps.

Comment: It seems that the else makes the problems. When I use it without a else, it works with mouse wheel and manual change position of scrollbar. Ill continue the troubleshooting. I think the (fadeTo 0) is not working with the and operator + between two sb positions.

Comment: That's so odd.  What you can do is after the first `fadeTo` return the function.  Then just put the second fade outside of the if statement completely.  I updated my answer to show what I'm talking about